# Will the TimeSpan which i set into DateTime.TimeOfDay change according to DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have variable `dtTime` of type `DateTime` and `tmSpan` of type `TimeSpan`. And i do these :

```
dtTime=new DateTime(1,1,1)+tmSpan;
```

After this if i change day time on `dtTime` this changes will be applied to `tmSpan` ? And if not is there any solution to apply something like this ?

Comment: [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)s are immutable - if you look at the methods available, you'll find that any method that involves mutating the value returns a *new* `TimeSpan` structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it wont. `tmSpan` is independent variable holding some value. Changes in `dtTime` will not change `tmSpan`.

For your second part of question, I am not sure how are you calculating the time span but I believe you have to recalculate it in order to get the changes, something like:

```
tmSpan = dtTime - DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing `dtTime` you can do

```
tmSpan = dtTime - new DateTime(1,1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this operation

```
dtTime=new DateTime(1,1,1)+tmSpan;
```

The part of the `TimeSpan` value is part of the `dtTime` instance and any changes to it won't be reflected back on the `TimeSpan`. you can still access the relevant parts by using `dtTime.TimeOfDay` which is what i think you are looking out for.